# Why does an IpcChannel tell me, "Cannot open an anonymous level security token?"

Tags: .net, remoting

I have a pretty simple client-server app that I am using to separate two components that can't live together in the same process. When developing them (the server is an exe, the client is a library), all my unit tests are happy as pigs in manure. When I move on to re-using the library elsewhere, I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: An error occurred while processing the request on the server: System.Security.SecurityException: Cannot open an anonymous level security token.

   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrentInternal(TokenAccessLevels desiredAccess, Boolean threadOnly)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.IpcServerTransportSink.ServiceRequest(Object state)
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer.
```

I have set up the remoting on both sides in code, rather than config files for simplicity at this stage. They are effectively identical:

```
BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider client = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider server = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
server.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;

Hashtable config = new Hashtable();
config["name"] = "SomeName";
config["portName"] = "SomePortName";

config["typeFilterLevel"] = "Full";
config["impersonate"] = "true";
config["tokenImpersonationLevel"] = "Impersonation";
config["useDefaultCredentials"] = "True";
config["secure"] = "True";

Channel = new IpcChannel(config, client, server);
```

So the question is: Why would the remoting framework want to create an anonymous token when impersonation is enabled? I've completely run out of places to look for answers on this.

Answer (score 0):

IT'S NOT AN ANSWER

I know it's an old question but maybe someone found a solution. I have similar setup to author's, but only identification level is required:

Server side:

```
Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
properties["authorizedGroup"] = GetUsersGroupName();
properties["name"] = configuration.ServiceShortName + ".Server";
properties["portName"] = configuration.ServiceGuid;
BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider sinkProvider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
sinkProvider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
Channel = new IpcServerChannel(properties, sinkProvider);
Channel.IsSecured = true;
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(Channel, true);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(AppManagerServer), configuration.ServerObjectUrl, WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);

string GetUsersGroupName()
{
        const string builtInUsersGroup = "S-1-5-32-545";
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(builtInUsersGroup);
NTAccount ntAccount = (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
        return ntAccount.Value;
}
```

Client side:

```
channel = new IpcClientChannel(AppManagerConfiguration.Instance.ServiceShortName + ".Client", null);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, true);
string appManagerUrl = "ipc://" + AppManagerConfiguration.Instance.ServiceGuid + "/" + AppManagerConfiguration.Instance.ServerObjectUrl;
(IAppManager)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IAppManager), appManagerUrl).DoSomething();
```

And then intermittently I get the following:
**An error occurred while processing the request on the server: System.Security.SecurityException: Cannot open an anonymous level security token.**

at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrentInternal(TokenAccessLevels desiredAccess, Boolean threadOnly)

at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.IpcServerTransportSink.ServiceRequest(Object state)

The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer